# Rails Nested Form - edit action & edit.html.erb won't display the form or related post content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I made a form where a user can dynamically add nested form fields by clicking a text or url button. When the form is submitted, the content displays in the view template. However, when I go to edit (& hopefully then update) a post at `/posts/id/edit`, the post content does not appear in the edit view template - it's a blank page in the browser.

[log of SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ueq.png)

Would really appreciate your help! Thank you!

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :things
end
```

**Things Model**

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "things", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.text     "text"
 t.string   "url"
 t.integer  "post_id"
end
```

**Posts Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end 

def update
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
 <button id='addtext'>text</button>
 <button id='addurl'>url</button>

 <%= form_for @post, url: posts_path, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

 <%= f.fields_for :thing do |ff| %>
 <% end %> 
 <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

**posts.coffee**

```
 current_index = 0

 addText = ->
 html = """
 <div>
 <textarea placeholder="Write something..."     name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][text]"     id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_text"></textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}]    [order]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_order" value="#{current_index}" />
 </div>
 """

$("#new_post input[type='submit']").before(html)
current_index += 1

$ ->
$('#addtext').on('click', addText)


current_index = 0
```

Comment: you should have a view called **edit.html.erb**

Comment: Apologies - I do, it has the same code as in the new.html.erb template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your structure:

1. You don't have any fields in your `form_for`
2. You're defining fields *manually* for `fields_for` (**BIG** no no).

---

**form_for**

When you create a `form_for`, Rails uses a [`form object`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) to take data from your `model`, and output it into an HTML form.

This output is done at render-time, and will not change regardless of how much manual lifting you do with javascript:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
   # you need fields in here
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The way to debug this is to check the `source` of your page (`Right-Click > View Source`). If the `<form>` element is present, it means the `form_for` method is working:

[image]

Also, remember that [`form_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) is a helper method. It takes arguments and outputs HTML for you to use. It's not magic. If it "doesn't show up", there has to be a logical reason for it.

---

**fields_for**

The second step is that your `fields_for` won't show up without having any objects to populate it.

You've also got a huge problem when you're manually adding new `fields_for` fields, which is basically an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

You'll need to do the following:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @post = Post.includes(:things).find(params[:id])
    @post.things.build unless @post.things.any?
  end
end

#app/views/posts/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @post, url: posts_path, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :things do |ff| %> #-> association name (plural)
     <%= ff.text_area :text, placeholder: "Write Something" %>
  <% end %> 

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

`fields_for` populates with the associated objects from the parent you passed to `form_for`. Thus if you have not built any of the associative objects, you need to ensure at least one is built, in order for the fields to be populated accordingly.

---

**Nested**

Lastly, you need to appreciate how to dynamically append `fields` to the `fields_for` block.

Whilst your code is not incorrect, it's highly impractical. There are swathes of resources to point you in the right direction:

> 1. [RailsCasts Nested Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amT27SfNhKM)
> 2. [`Cocoon`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) Gem (HIGHLY recommended)
> 3. [NoMethodError within nested model form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649598/nomethoderror-within-nested-model-form) (my own post)

In short, you need to use Ruby/Rails to build the `fields_for` methods you require, appending them to your form with ajax:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @post = Post.includes(:things).find params[:id]
    @post.things.build unless @post.things.any?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
end

#app/views/posts/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @post, authenticity_token: !request.xhr? do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: "things_fields", locals: { f: f } %>
  <% if !request.xhr? %>
    <%= button_to "Add Thing", edit_posts_path(@post), method: :get, remote: true %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

#app/views/posts/_things_fields.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :things, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.text_area :text, placeholder: "Write Something" %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to append the `fields` through a `JS` call:

```
#app/views/posts/edit.js.erb
$("<%=j render "edit" %>").data().appendTo("form#post);
```

The trick with this method is the use of `child_index: Time.now.to_i` (providing a unique `id` for each newly appended field).

--

Long post; you've got my email if you want me to go through it specifically with you.